# Como obter o Package Name de um aplicativo Android numa library em C?

Tags: android, c, packages, jni, android-ndk

Gostaria de saber como posso obter o Package Name do meu APP Android através de uma biblioteca escrita em **C**.

O que pretendo obter é o seguinte `com/meu_app/mainframe/MainActivity` ou `com.meu_app.mainframe.MainActivity` da classe que esta carregando a biblioteca `com/meu_app/mainframe/MainActivity.java` ou onde for utilizada a função `public native String hello();` com `System.loadLibrary("getpackagename");`

Com o package name obtido gostaria de utiliza-lo na função `int runcmd(void)` imprimindo no `__android_log_print`.

Existem muitos exemplos, mas eles não estão bem claros para mim, pois não demonstram como utilizar a função, ou como implementa-las do inicio ao fim.

Tenho uma função simples, que talvez ajude se for modificada para obter o package name, está abaixo.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_simple_example_MainActivity_Native_Hello(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz)
{
    runcmd();
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "-------------hello world runcmd().-------------");
}


int runcmd(void)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "-----from--jni-------", "Enter RUN CMD function!");

//__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "-----from--jni-------", "Imprime o a string PackageName %s\n", pkg_name);

}


static JNINativeMethod gMethods[] = {
        { "hello", "()Ljava/lang/String;", (void*)Java_com_simple_example_MainActivity_Native_Hello },
        }; /* * Register several native methods for one class. */

static int registerNativeMethods(JNIEnv* env, const char* className, JNINativeMethod* gMethods, int numMethods)
{
    jclass clazz;
    clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, className);
    if (clazz == NULL)
    {
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }
    if ((*env)->RegisterNatives(env, clazz, gMethods, numMethods) < 0)
    {
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    return JNI_TRUE; }

/* * Register native methods for all classes we know about. */
static int registerNatives(JNIEnv* env)
{
    if (!registerNativeMethods(env, JNIREG_CLASS, gMethods, sizeof(gMethods) / sizeof(gMethods[0])))
    {
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }
    return JNI_TRUE;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    JNIEnv* env = NULL;
    jint result = -1;
    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    assert(env != NULL);
    if (!registerNatives(env))//??
    {
        return -1;
    }
    /* success -- return valid version number */
    result = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
    return result;
}
```

No Android Studio podemos chamar a função hello() da seguinte forma:

```
public class MainActivity ...
public native String hello();

static{
    System.loadLibrary("getpackagename");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    //Log.d("StackTraceElement", String.valueOf(stackTraceElements[2]));
    hello();
}
```

> Não pretendo passar esse valor como uma *"string"*, quero dizer, não seria
>   bom obter isso com um StackTraceElement e passa-lo através do hello(),
>   gostaria de obtê-lo diretamente na biblioteca em C.

Entenda melhor...

> Uma forma fácil de resolver isso seria obter o Package Name no
>   APP/java e passar para a library via String, mas esse valor poderia ser
>   setado/modificado e não obtido do APP, a ideia é impedir quem estiver usando a
>   library que escolha o package, pois ele iria ser obtido apenas na
>   library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Como obter o APP Package Name do Android no JNI?*
Abaixo, mostro um exemplo completo de implementação, de como obtê-lo se forma simples em uma library.

Obtemos o `context` através da `jstring context` na library.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_simple_example_MainActivity_Native_Hello(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring context)
{

    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/content/ContextWrapper");
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring packageName = (jstring)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context, mid);

    //Faz a conversão do jstring para o char *, para que possa ser usado no __android_log_print
    const char *nativeString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, packageName, 0);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "--packageName--jni--", "%s", nativeString);

    runcmd();
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "-------------hello world runcmd().-------------");
}


int runcmd(void)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "-----from--jni-------", "Enter RUN CMD function!");

//__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "-----from--jni-------", "Imprime o a string PackageName %s\n", pkg_name);

}

#define JNIREG_CLASS "com/simple/example/MainActivity"

/** * Table of methods associated with a single class. */
static JNINativeMethod gMethods[] = {
        { "hello", "()Ljava/lang/String;", (void*)Java_com_simple_example_MainActivity_Native_Hello },
        }; /* * Register several native methods for one class. */

static int registerNativeMethods(JNIEnv* env, const char* className, JNINativeMethod* gMethods, int numMethods)
{
    jclass clazz;
    clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, className);
    if (clazz == NULL)
    {
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }
    if ((*env)->RegisterNatives(env, clazz, gMethods, numMethods) < 0)
    {
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    return JNI_TRUE; }

/* * Register native methods for all classes we know about. */
static int registerNatives(JNIEnv* env)
{
    if (!registerNativeMethods(env, JNIREG_CLASS, gMethods, sizeof(gMethods) / sizeof(gMethods[0])))
    {
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }
    return JNI_TRUE;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    JNIEnv* env = NULL;
    jint result = -1;
    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    assert(env != NULL);
    if (!registerNatives(env))//??
    {
        return -1;
    }
    /* success -- return valid version number */
    result = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
    return result;
}
```

No Android Studio, podemos utilizar o seguinte.

```
@SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")
public native String hello(Context context);
hello(this);
```

Com essas poucas modificações, é possível obter o `com.meu_app.mainframe`.
Modificações simples, mas que não achei em lugar algum.

Comment: Melhorias no código são aceitas, assim como opções alternativas. Foi difícil, mas está aí. =)