# Qual a diferença entre esses dois meios de obter o PackageName?

Tags: android, c, packages, jni

Estou com esses dois trechos de códigos, os dois exibem o mesmo resultado, então gostaria de saber, qual a diferença entre eles.

## 1

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/content/ContextWrapper");
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

jstring packageNamei = (jstring)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context, mid);
const char *nativeString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, packageNamei, 0);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "--packageName--jni--", "%s", nativeString);
```

## 2

```
jclass context_clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, context);

jmethodID methodID_pack = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, context_clazz, 
"getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring application_package = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context, methodID_pack);
const char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, application_package, 0);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "JNI", "PackageName: %s\n", str);
```

Posso usar qualquer um deles, ou algum é mais recomendado?

Comment: Porque você quer fazer isso em JNI?

Comment: É para pegar o package name do app android, daria para fazer de outra forma? Estou recebendo o `context` da `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Se tem um *context* pode obter o *Package name* através de `context.getPackageName();`

Comment: Na _library_ @ramaral?

Comment: O que quer dizer com *library*? Só dá se estiver a programar em java.

Comment: O foco é a biblioteca em C, obter o pakage name apenas no C, na library compilada, sei como obter no java, o código que eu estou usando requer o `context`, que só consegui através da `MainActivity.java` talvez essa minha outra [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145869/8984) te ajude a entender melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No caso 1**

`FindClass` pegará a referência da classe a partir do nome dela, ou seja, pra você pegar a referência da classe você deverá saber o nome dela e sua assinatura completa. Exemplo da classe `String`:

***Nome*** `String`

***Assinatura completa*** `java.lang.String` - porém deve-se substituir os pontos por barras `"java/lang/String"`

**No caso 2**
`GetObjectClass` pegará a referência da classe a partir de um objeto, ou seja, você não precisa saber o nome da classe, o próprio objeto contém essa informação e o `GetObjectClass` pegará a referência da classe a qual o objeto foi instanciado. Caso a classe, a qual esse objeto pertence, não possuir o método que você está buscando, provavelmente `GetObjectClass` irá gerar uma exceção `NoSuchMethodError`. O segundo argumento de `GetObjectClass` é a referência do objeto:

```
jclass GetObjectClass(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
```

Especificamente para o trecho de código do seu segundo caso, a função `GetObjectClass` pode ser usado no caso de o várias classes que possuem o mesmo método, como as classes que herdam um método de uma mesma classe pai. Dessa forma não importa qual classe o objeto instanciado pertence pois todas as classes herdam o mesmo método.

O uso delas vai depender do objetivo de sua função nativa.

Segue link com mais informações sobre as funções de operações de classe: [JNI Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#class_operations)

A partir dessas informações você pode julgar qual delas servirá melhor pra sua necessidade.